# How to get updates from gitlab API if topics changed?

Tags: hash, gitlab, md5, gitlab-api, crc32

`updated_at` or `last_activity_at` don't have any effect on changing a topic. But i really would need to have this info.

Is there a way or do anyone have an idea how i can notice if topics are changed ?

I need this info because a cron script is updating project informations in a database and we have database topics referring to the git topics.

I'm thankful for every help.

Thank you !

### EDIT:

What do you think of something like a hash ? The script is hashing all the topics into 1 field into the database and when checking for updates i check the projects hash from the database against the one i got from the API ?

Which one you prefer or will be the best type of hashing a string ?
MD5, HASH or CRC32 ?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.